# Android EditText into Listview actiondone

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

In my Listview, for every line I see a EditText. Now, I want to see the button "done" on the keyboard when the EditText is focused.
I used imeOptions, but the keyboard appears the button "return". What can I do?

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:id="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:hint="Note"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your single attribute:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```